# Windows 7: What is the event ID for a lock event and how to tell if it is user-initiated or not?

Tags: windows-7, windows, event-viewer

The following `eventvwr.exe` event relates to a `screen unlock event`:

Event ID 4624 (access type: 7) (screen unlock)

Now I need to find the `screen lock event`, so I can compare the time between when I left the apartment and when the screen locked. If the difference is more than what is set as the screen lock time in the control panel, I will know someone logged on while I was away. Thanks.

NOTE:

I'm confused because [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11385164/eventviewer-eventid-for-lock-and-unlock) tells another story.

Comment: Event IDs 528, 538, and 680 are for Windows Server 2000
Windows 2003 and XP

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In Windows 7, How to query times, when the computer was locked?](http://superuser.com/questions/528884/in-windows-7-how-to-query-times-when-the-computer-was-locked)

Answer (score 3):

#### What is the event ID for a lock event and how to tell if it is user-initiated or not?

If a user locks the workstation and then immediately unlocks the workstation the following events are logged (read from the bottom up in the image):

[image]

- 4800 The workstation was locked
- 4648 A logon was attempted using explicit credentials
- 4624 An account was successfully logged on
- 4672 Special privileges assigned to new logon
- 4801 The workstation was unlocked

---

#### 4800: The workstation was locked

> - When either a user manually locks his workstation or the workstation automatically locks its console after a period of inactivity this
>     event is logged.
> - To find out when the user returned and unlocked the workstation look for event ID 4801.
> - If a screen saver is used, there is a relationship between this event and 4802/4803  See event ID 4802 for an explanation of the
>     sequence of events.
>
> **Description Fields**
>
> The user and logon session involved.
>
> - Security ID:  The SID of the account.
> - Account Name: The account logon name.
> - Account Domain: The domain or - in the case of local accounts - computer name.
> - Logon ID is a semi-unique (unique between reboots) number that identifies the logon session.  Logon ID allows you to correlate
>     backwards to the logon event (4624) as well as with other events
>     logged during the same logon session.

Source [4800: The workstation was locked](https://www.ultimatewindowssecurity.com/securitylog/encyclopedia/event.aspx?eventid=4800)

---

#### 4801: The workstation was unlocked

> - When a user unlocks his workstation you will see this event.
> - To find out when the workstation was previously locked look backwards in time for for event ID 4800.
> - If a screen saver is used, there is also a relationship between this event and 4802 (screen saver invoked) and 4803 (screen saver
>     dismissed).
> - For Interactive logons you may see this event or 4803.

Source [4801: The workstation was unlocked](https://www.ultimatewindowssecurity.com/securitylog/encyclopedia/event.aspx?eventid=4801)

---

#### 4624: An account was successfully logged on

> - This is a highly valuable event since it documents each and every successful attempt to logon to the local computer regardless of logon
>     type, location of the user or type of account.
> - You can tie this event to logoff events 4634 and 4647 using Logon ID.

Source [4624: An account was successfully logged on](https://www.ultimatewindowssecurity.com/securitylog/encyclopedia/event.aspx?eventid=4624)

---

#### What is the difference between windows events 4801 and 4624?

- Event ID 4624 is generated when an account successfully logs on.
- Event ID 4801 is generated when the workstation is unlocked.
- You get both of these events when a user unlocks the workstation.

---

#### Further Reading

- [Windows Security Log Events](https://www.ultimatewindowssecurity.com/securitylog/encyclopedia/Default.aspx?catid=2)
- [Tracking User Logon Activity Using Logon Events](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericfitz/archive/2008/08/20/tracking-user-logon-activity-using-logon-events.aspx)

Comment: Then what is the difference between Event ID 4624 (access type: 7) and Event ID 4801: The workstation was unlocked?

Comment: You see both. Look at the sequence of events at the start of my answer.

Comment: You have to logon **before** the workstation unlock is generated. For example, if you give the wrong password the logon will fail and the workstation will not unlock.

Comment: Yeah, I'm just not getting events 4800 and 4801 on my version of Windows.

Comment: The wrong password will generate `4625: An account failed to log on`

Comment: I don't think my intruders would be too stupid to try that, it's just that I don't know where else to look to see if there were any accesses betwen 12>35 and 14:37.

Comment: Did you try my suggestion "Were you logged in as an Adminstrator when you tried to copy the directories? Can you try just copy the contents of C:\SysWOW64\GroupPolicy and paste to C:\Windows\System32\GroupPolicy? Note C:\SysWOW64\GroupPolicyUser is an empty directory so that shouldn't be a problem"? from [Windows 7 (Home Premium): eventvwr.exe: How to log workstation locking and unlocking and screensaver invoked and dismissed events](http://superuser.com/q/991597)

Comment: Tried your suggestion with no luck.

Comment: See my answer [Restrict device installation using Registry Editor against BadUSB](http://superuser.com/a/966847), there a batch file that might work for you. You have to modify the batch file as per the instructions.

Comment: So your "intruders" know the password? Why don't you just change the password? Or lock the screen **before** you leave?

Comment: Because 1. it's too late, and 2. I forgot to lock the screen today.

Comment: Aaah........ :(

Comment: I think without 4800 and 4801you are out of luck.

Comment: I hate Windows for this. And I hate Firefox for displaying all the passwords at one click. And I hate Google Drive for not logging the date and time of read-only accesses.

Comment: Firefox - use a master password. Google Drive - encrypt it with https://www.boxcryptor.com/en/google-drive